# Move R Shiny showNotification to a certain div

Tags: css, r, shiny

Closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112000/move-r-shiny-shownotification-to-center-of-screen), I am trying to move the `showNotification`´s to a certain `div` that is already on the page. Is there an easy way to do that?

The following app should illustrate the problem. The notifications in the lower right should go in the yellow div.

```
library(shiny)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
                  tags$head(
                    tags$style(HTML("
                                    #error {
                                      width: 100%;
                                      border: black 1px solid;
                                      padding: 5px;
                                      margin: 10px 0;
                                      background-color: #f7f2d9;
                                    }
                                    "))
                  ),
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      sliderInput("lambda","Number",min = 1,max = 100,value = 27)
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      h3("Move the slider above 28 to trigger a Notification! "),
                      plotOutput("algebra"),
                      div(id = "error", p("The notifications should appear in here")),
                      tableOutput('table')
                    )
                  )
))

server=function(input, output) {
  output$algebra <- renderPlot({
    if (input$lambda > 28){
      showNotification("How can I put this message in the #error div?", id = "error", type = "warning", duration = NULL)
      return(NULL)
    }
    n <- 1:100
    lambda <- seq(min(n), max(n), length.out = input$lambda)
    plot((2*lambda)+3, type = "o",xlab= "X (number of data points)", ylab = "Y = 2x+3")
  })

  output$table <- renderTable(iris)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    #error {
                      width: 100%;
                      border: black 1px solid;
                      padding: 5px;
                      margin: 10px 0;
                      background-color: #f7f2d9;
                    }
                    #shiny-notification-panel {
                      position: static;
                    }
                    "))
  ),
  ......
```

and in `server`:

```
  output$algebra <- renderPlot({
    if(input$lambda > 28){
      showNotification("How can I put this message in the #error div?", type = "warning", duration = NULL)
      runjs('setTimeout(function(){$("#error").append($("#shiny-notification-panel"))},0);')
      return(NULL)
    }
    ......
```

Not highly tested though. An alternative is `bsAlert` from the `shinyBS` package.

Comment: Great thank you, that works. I'm not sure though if the `setTimeout` is necessary? It seems to work without it aswell.

Comment: @SeGa Maybe it is not necessary, I have not tested.