# Show shiny notification in sidebar

Tags: r, shiny

In the example below, the 'Selections Saved' notification appears in the bottom-right corner of the application. Instead I would like it to appear in the sidebar (either directly under the action button, or simply at the bottom left of the side-bar):

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton("apply", "Save Selections")
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  observeEvent(input$apply, {
    showNotification("Selections Saved", duration = 2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I know that there are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112000/move-r-shiny-shownotification-to-center-of-screen) already, but these result in the notification being shown in the middle of the screen, rather than in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to just change the percentages?

```
# bottom-left
custom_notes <- HTML(
  "
  .shiny-notification {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(0%);
    left: calc(100%);
  }
  "
)
```

And them put `tags$head(tags$style(custom_notes))` inside `ui`, before the dashboard elements?